# "Embed" iframe web part not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, embedded

I have been experimenting with the new SharePoint communication sites, and I love the new web parts. However, I've been having an issue with the "Embed" web part. I understand that it only takes iFrames, but I'm having two different issues with it.

1. When I try to embed a post from Facebook (from which I can create a custom iframe embed code) it doesn't work - even though Facebook is listed as an approved site in my SharePoint tenant. I get a message that says "We can't show this embedded content because the code seems to be incomplete. Make sure that the embed code includes width, height and a valid address for the src attribute. "
2. Sites like instagram and twitter don't export embed codes using iframe, so I have been trying to write my own, but those don't work either.

I am able to get embeds from YouTube working. Any idea why this could be failing?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I'm able to embed FB post in embed webpart. If there are no height, width specified then you will get this error. Make sure that you specified it.

Comment: Thank you. Are you  using the iframe that Facebook gives you or writing your own?

Comment: I typed iframe tag manually. And added only url of FB post as src of iframe.

Comment: Can you post an example of the code that is working? Using any random facebook post is fine. If it doesn't work for me then it's something wrong with how I've added the site to field security, or something entirely different.

Comment: <iframe src="My FB post url" height="500" width="700">
</iframe>

Comment: thank you! It's unfortunately still not working. I added a picture to the post above to show that the site is added. My error message now says: Embedding content from this website isn't allowed, but your admin can change this setting. They will need to add 'www.facebook.com' to the list of sites that are allowed. (which I have done - see post above)

Answer (score 0):

For me, only user that has at least Design permission at the root of the SharePoint site can embed a Facebook video

Perhaps someone with more knowledge can add to this